# There is an exception in Crystal Reports on client machine

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I got the error mentioned as below on client machine. For some systems it is working well but for some I get the error mentioned as below:

See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. 
>   An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: Sounds like you have a bitness-failure.  Check to ensure you don't have a mix of **x86; x64** in project build settings. On x64 Windows, a .NET .exe marked as **Any CPU** will fail if it attempts to load a dll built as **x86**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It could be useful to someone: if you have the option to do it, go to IIS and set the Application Pool to 32 bit applications only.

That made the trick for me.

- (Of course, your application could be made to run only on 64 bit. In that case, I think the installing of the 64 bit redistributable of CrystalReports should solve the issue)